# Aiogram Как сделать бан пользователей при повторном отправлении сообщения из черного списка

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Так организован бан пользователей за использование слов, которые находятся в черном списке, как сделать что бы бан пользователей происходил не сразу, а например после пяти написаний слов из черного списка

```
 for word in cfg.bad_words:
            if word in text:
                await message.delete()
                await bot.ban_chat_member(chat_id=cfg.CHAT_ID, user_id=message.from_user.id, until_date=datetime.now() + timedelta(days=1))
```

Comment: создать в бд таблицу со счетчиком слов для каждого юзера. И после каждого слово из ЧС увеличивать счетчик, при достижении 5 - банить.

Comment: без бд же можно, что-то вроде задать какой-то count и после каждого удаленного сообщения прибавлять один и потом сравнивать if count > 5 вызывать бан, но count не плюсуется